# How to set new model info in specific nested array of objects using Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple contact form when submitted should set the values inside the contacts section of my model, I have done very little settings/saving on a model so I'm wondering if there is anything in particular to set to a specific part of the model?

**JS**
Data to save (myNewContactObject)

```
{
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
  "telephone": "0123456789"
}
```

Should save to nested contacts array of model, example structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "model name",
    "teams": [
      {
        "name": "team one name"
      },
      {
        "name": "team two name"
      }
    ],
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "James Smith",
        "email": "james@gkugi.com",
        "telephone": "18917391847"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can I literally just do `this.model.set(myNewContactObject)? or do I need to do something like this.model.contacts.set(myNewContactObject)?`

Or, maybe this approach is wrong and I should be making a `collection out of the contacts` like `ContactsCollection` and setting each `ContactModel` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's `Model.set` has the following syntax:

`this.model.set('attribute-name', 'attribute-value')`

So to set the attribute "contacts" to your complex array object, you would do something like:

```
var contacts = this.model.get('contacts');
contacts.push(myNewContactObject);
```

Note in this case, since arrays are passed by-reference in JavaScript, there is no need to make a `contacts.set` call; the .get() call returns a reference through which you mutate the contacts array directly.  However, if you built a new array:

`var newContacts = [myNewContactObject];`

You need to set it like so:

`this.model.set('contacts', newContacts);`

Note that the attribute you wish to modify is passed as an argument, not referenced as a property of the model, so the `this.model.contacts.set` syntax you mention will not work in any case.

Keep in mind that Backbone will let you set a complex object as the value of the attribute, but it will not help you mine that attribute to arbitrary depth.  To do something like that, you need a Backbone plugin like `backbone-deep-model`, which can be installed with both `npm install` and `bower install`.  This would allow you to this:

`this.model.get('contacts.0.name')`

Without something like this, you can only do:

`this.model.get('contacts')` and then parse out the contact/property you want yourself.

You could also do as you mention, and create a collection of contacts, but this largely depends on how you plan on modeling your data in your backend.  If you have a relational API setup on the back-end, something like `api/v1/persons/<person-id>/contacts`, then you may want to create contact collections with that URL and have a related collection for each person.  In this case, yes, each contact object in your array would actually be it's own model, and your 'array' would really be a Backbone.Collection.  Whether this is the correct approach depends on your modeling.

If you are interested in doing this, you may want to look into `backbone-relational`, although the concept of doing relational data with Backbone is an area of some debate.